# Facebook validation for like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have created Facebook registration page, What i want to do is user can register once they have clicked the like button otherwise it should say like "Click on the Like Button" something like that.so system should check whether the button has been clicked or not.any one aware of it?

Comment: I guess Facebook will validate it and you need not have to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your site appears in the user's likes feed:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/UID/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It it does then proceed with registration, else redirect their attention to the like button